# PHP Copy and manipulate XML

Tags: php, xml

i have an MPD File for a DASH Playlist and have to read the time, manipulate the data path and save it into a new xml.

My xml is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500000S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M7.53S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011, http://dashif.org/guildelines/dash264">
 <Period duration="PT0H0M7.53S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080" maxFrameRate="11988/400" par="16:9" lang="und">
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640028" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="11988/400" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="244587">
    <BaseURL>1080p_00-intro_track1_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="906-949">
      <Initialization range="0-905"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="11988/400" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="155529">
    <BaseURL>720p_00-intro_track1_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="904-947">
      <Initialization range="0-903"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
    ...
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet>
    ...
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

I got the duration by:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($introFile);
duration = $xml->Period['duration'];
```

But with simpleXML it is hard to direct copy some parts from it and save it to a new xml file. I only need the data in the Period Tag but also the  has to be set to "dash/1080p_00-intro_track1_dashinit.mp4".

How can I do something like that? Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: XSLT [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php), [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML isn't particularly good at copying data like this, but DOMDocument can make it quite easy.

Assuming you want to copy the `<Period>` nodes, use `getElementsByTagName()` to fetch all the matching tags in the source `$doc`.  It first imports this node from the source to the new XML file (`$new`) and for each of these, it also looks at the `<BaseURL>` tags and loops over all of these tags and adds in the new part of the part.  This newly manipulated node is then added into the new document to the root element (you can tweak the root node in the line `$new->loadXML('<?xml vers...`) ...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);

$new = new DOMDocument();
$new->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?><MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" />');

$copy = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Period");
foreach ( $copy as $period )    {
    $copyNode = $new->importNode($period, true);
    $baseURLs = $copyNode->getElementsByTagName("BaseURL");
    foreach ( $baseURLs as $baseURL )   {
        $baseURL->nodeValue = "dash/".$baseURL->nodeValue;
    }
    $new->documentElement->appendChild($copyNode);
}

echo $new->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I appreciate it very much!

Only one short question left. Access the Period duration attribute is still better with SimpleXML or is there a better way with DomDocument too? Because then I didn't need to open the file to times (one time simpleXML/one time DOM)?

Comment: If you need the duration in the loop, you can just use `$period->getAttribute("duration")`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

I have a meeting now but I test it on the weekend and report my result on monday! But it sounds pretty nice!

Comment: I tested this solution and it works for me! Thanks a lot! :)